# How to debug a core file without any executable provided by customer

Tags: debugging, gdb

Is it possible to debug a customer provided core file, without any executable available to us, using gdb ?? Source is written in C or C++.

Comment: That question makes no sense. Do you have the source? Or only the produced exe? Or neither? If you have the source or the exe then you can debug it (at some level). If you have neither then unless you have some sort of telepathy, well what can I say.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible

Not with default core configuration, no.